# Generating a random number between 0 and x (Java)

Tags: java, random, cryptography

Using the Xorshift random number generator... I already have the generator, but I haven't been able to modify it to give a number between 0 and an upper limit (like the `nextInt()` method in the Java Random class).

```
  long seed = System.nanoTime();

  int next(int nbits) {
    long x = seed;
    x ^= (x << 21);
    x ^= (x >>> 35);
    x ^= (x << 4);
    seed = x;
    x &= ((1L << nbits) -1);
    return (int) x;
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you use `((int)x) % (upper_limit + 1)`? (That's a sincere question; I don't know enough about the properties of Xorshift -- specifically, about how much entropy it has in the lower bits -- to know if that's a good idea.)

Comment: Use the remainder function - n % x

Comment: I thought about this but I had a feeling it would affect the cryptographic strength. Is there no reason why it should have any effect on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can see what java does with [random class](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/Random-source.html)

Comment: The OP is aware of this class, since they mentioned it in the question.

Comment: I know, but I believe the OP never read the source code of that class or he would been able to solve the problem. So I link the sources.

Comment: @PaulBellora: But (s)he may not have been aware that there's an open-source implementation of that class. (Note that this answer links directly to source-code.)

Comment: @ruakh correct, and in that source file there are also clear comments and explanation about that task.